# NestJS DTO extended with PartialType breaks validation

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, dto, class-validator

With two DTO in NestJS
given `class ADto` & `class BDto`
`class ADto extends PartialType(BDto)` type-coercion fails.
(Params are not converted to number from string, resulting in class-validator throwing an error).

If `class ADto extends BDto`, all works.

Why does using PartialType not include type-coercion?

Comment: To me it seems to be working but I'm probably using different approach. Can you give an example you're trying?

Comment: I'm using `class-validator` in `ADto` `@IsNumber` and if I use `PartialType` in extending the attribute which is supposed to be a number remains a string and I get a `400` error saying the param needs to be a number. However if I don't use `PartialType` I don't have the issue. All type coercion is happening in `main.ts` ```app.useGlobalPipes(
new ValidationPipe({ transform: true,  transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true, }})```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the `class-validator` library simply [does not support generics](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-generics) (which `Partial<T>` types are):

> Generics are not supported because TypeScript does not have good
> reflection abilities yet. Once TypeScript team provide us better
> runtime type reflection tools, generics will be implemented.

Comment: So if `class-validator` created a new class with the included properties instead of just using the `Partial<T>` directly then this would work? (the documentation mentions `plainToClassFromExist` as the workaround to avoid using a generic). I guess in my case of DTO objects I would just need to maintain two classes and decorate all the properties as optional on the `Update` DTO (since only the `Create` DTO requires all fields)? Unless I'm missing something this is not great with respect to having single responsibility for validation.